# Makefile: prerequisites with spaces

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Update: GNU Make 3.81, Ubuntu 12.04

I have a set of markdown files that I want to compile to (say) html files, so this is my rule:

```
%.html: %.md
    pandoc $< -o $@
```

So `make foo.html` would convert `foo.md` into `foo.html`.

However, **there are spaces in the source markdown filenames and I do not have the ability to control these**, that is I can't change a setting to remove the spaces.

This means if I `make foo\ bar.html`, I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `foo bar.html'. Stop.
```

**How can I write a generic rule `%.html: %.md` where the prerequisite filename has spaces?**

I can get around it by using:

```
foo\ bar.html: foo\ bar.md
    pandoc $< -o $@
```

But then I must manually write out this rule for every such source file that I have, when I'd rather use the `%` construct. Is my only hope to do some sort of `$(foreach f,$(get list of *.md files),$(eval $(call function_to_generate_rule)))`?

Comment: Make really doesn't handle spaces in target names well. I suspect that any solution you find will be an ugly kludge.

Comment: In trying to reproduce your issue, putting `%.html: %.md` `markdown $< > $@`, I cannot get the `make` error about not finding the target. Which version of make are you using?

Comment: You do know that for `make` to do inference properly, the source file `foo bar.md` has to either exist or be something that `make` knows how to build, right?

Comment: @binki: of course, `foo bar.md` does exist. GNU make 3.81. I can reproduce this.

Comment: OK, I see the issue on GNU make 3.81 on Windows but not on GNU make 3.82 on GNU.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 12.04 so cannot update my `make` any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems from what @binki says that GNU make 3.82 might not have this issue, but unfortunately I do not have the option to update from v3.81 that is on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

I managed to "solve" it like so by using SECONDEXPANSION to substitute spaces with backslash-space in the prerequisite (so a prerequisite of `foo bar.md` becomes `foo\ bar.md`).

```
# define a variable with a single space
space:=
space+=

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.html: $$(subst $$(space),\$$(space),%).md
   pandoc "$<" -o "$@"
```

[Here is the log](http://pastebin.com/rR3YeFwK). Again, works on Ubuntu 12.04/GNU Make 3.81, perhaps if you have 3.82 you can use @binki's solution which seems more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Apparently make’s support for whitespace in inference rules depends on what variant of GNU Make you are using. It just magically works fine with Gentoo’s patched sys-devel/make-3.82-r4 (and fails with Gentoo’s make 3.81-r2). I did not notice any explanation in make-3.82’s ChangeLog or NEWS or the Gentoo patches when quickly checking them. So implicit rules working with whitespace could just be a fluke in make-3.82 itself or even from Gentoo’s patchset. Official GNU support for whitespace in targets is tracked in the still-open [GNU Make bug #712](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?712).

### Original misguided answer

You can use any quoting characters that your shell supports. `make` ignores them when performing macro substitution and passes them directly to the shell. For example,

```
.SUFFIXES: .md .html
.md.html:
    pandoc "$(<)" > "$(@)"
```

results in `$ make foo\ bar.html` passing the shell `pandoc "foo bar.md" > "foo bar.html"`. I decided to use the traditional style of specifying generic `make` rules instead of the GNU Make extension involving `%`, but you can do this with GNU Make’s `%`-style rules too, I assume.

This does not solve the potential problem of the filenames containing quote characters in them. I think that, simply, most people just avoid putting `"` or `'` in filenames because of the likelihood of causing issues with `Makefile`s or other scripts. Or you could use a GNU Makefile extension to replace the `"` characdter with `\"`, something that makes `sh` happy (we’re going to just ignore `cmd` for now because I don’t even…):

```
.SUFFIXES: .md .html
.md.html:
    pandoc "$(subst ",\",$(<))" > "$(subst ",\",$(@))"
```

This was tested with a file called `a"b"c.md` which succeeded in creating `a"b"c.html` (disclaimer: I used discount’s `markdown` command instead of pandoc).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about suffix rules. However, [the GNU makefule book](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) says suffix rules are obsolete. In any case, when I try your first makefile above, I get the same error.

Comment: See [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8KrYRuaW) showing me trying this makefile. bash shell.